# QGIS C++ API doesn't work with ECW files

Tags: qgis, raster, c++, ecw, standalone

I'm new with QGIS. After lots of trying I finally executed a successful compile on QGIS libs and used them in my program. In my simple program I just read some layers (vector and raster) and showed them in a QGIS canvas. This is my code and I use `qgis-dev 3.13` libraries.

```
 // QGIS Includes
#include "QApplication"
#include "qgsapplication.h"
#include "qgsproviderregistry.h"
#include "qgssinglesymbolrenderer.h"
#include "qgsvectorlayer.h"
#include "qgsrasterlayer.h"
#include "qgsmapcanvas.h"
#include "qgsproject.h"
#include "qgsrasterrenderer.h"
#include "qgssinglebandpseudocolorrenderer.h"
#include "qgscolorrampshader.h"
#include "qgsrastershader.h"
#include "qgshillshaderenderer.h"
#include "qgsmaplayerstyle.h"
#include "qgsrastertransparency.h"
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{

    // Start the Application
    QApplication a(argc,argv);
    QgsApplication app(argc, argv, true);

   QgsApplication::setPluginPath("C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-dev/lib");
    QgsApplication::setPrefixPath("C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-dev");
    QApplication::addLibraryPath("C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-dev/lib");
    QgsProviderRegistry::instance("C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/gdal-dev/bin/gdalplugins");

    QgsApplication::initQgis();


   // QgsVectorLayer *vectLayer = new QgsVectorLayer("E:/QGISProject/Shape_Files/iran-administrative/iran_administrative.shp","vectLayer","ogr");
    QgsRasterLayer *rastLayer = new QgsRasterLayer("C:/Users/Test/Desktop/build-testQGISLib-Desktop_Qt_5_12_1_MSVC2015_64bit-Release/release/j37g41.tif","rastLayer");
   // QgsRasterLayer *rast3dLayer = new QgsRasterLayer("C:/Users/Test/Desktop/build-testQGISLib-Desktop_Qt_5_12_1_MSVC2015_64bit-Release/release/j37g41.tif");
    QgsRasterLayer *ecwLayer = new QgsRasterLayer("C:/Users/Test/Downloads/Compressed/I33a1_Ecw/I33a1.ecw");

    QgsMapCanvas *mapcanvas = new QgsMapCanvas();
    QList<QgsMapLayer*> layers;


    //rast3dLayer = rastLayer;

    /*if(vectLayer->isValid())
        cout<<"it's ok"<<endl;
    else {
        cout<<"it is not ok"<<endl;   }


    vectLayer->updateExtents();*/



      QgsRasterShader *rasterShader = new QgsRasterShader();
      QgsColorRampShader *colorRampShader = new QgsColorRampShader();
      colorRampShader->setColorRampType( QgsColorRampShader::Interpolated );

      //items to imitate old pseudo color renderer
      QList<QgsColorRampShader::ColorRampItem> colorRampItems;
      QgsColorRampShader::ColorRampItem firstItem;
      firstItem.value = 0.0;
      firstItem.color = QColor( 0, 0, 255 );
      colorRampItems.append( firstItem );
      QgsColorRampShader::ColorRampItem secondItem;
      secondItem.value = 1500.0;
      secondItem.color = QColor( 0, 255, 255 );
      colorRampItems.append( secondItem );
      QgsColorRampShader::ColorRampItem thirdItem;
      thirdItem.value = 3000.0;
      thirdItem.color = QColor( 255, 255, 0 );
      colorRampItems.append( thirdItem );
      QgsColorRampShader::ColorRampItem fourthItem;
      fourthItem.value = 4500;
      fourthItem.color = QColor( 255, 0, 0 );
      colorRampItems.append( fourthItem );
      colorRampShader->setColorRampItemList( colorRampItems );
      rasterShader->setRasterShaderFunction( colorRampShader );


      QgsSingleBandPseudoColorRenderer *rasterRenderer = new QgsSingleBandPseudoColorRenderer( rastLayer->dataProvider(), 1, rasterShader );
      //QgsHillshadeRenderer *renderer3d = new QgsHillshadeRenderer(rast3dLayer->dataProvider(), 1, 274.0, 45.0);

     rastLayer->dataProvider()->setNoDataValue( 1, 126 );


    QgsProject::instance()->addMapLayer(rastLayer);
    //QgsProject::instance()->addMapLayer(rast3dLayer);
    //renderer3d->setOpacity(.5);
    rasterRenderer->setOpacity(1.0);
    rastLayer->setRenderer( rasterRenderer );

    //layers.append(rast3dLayer);
    layers.append(ecwLayer);
    //layers.append(vectLayer);
    layers.append(rastLayer);




    mapcanvas->setExtent(rastLayer->extent());
    mapcanvas->setLayers(layers);
    mapcanvas->zoomToFullExtent();
    //mapcanvas->setCanvasColor(QColor::Rgb);
    mapcanvas->setCanvasColor("white");
    cout<<"rend is "<< mapcanvas->layer(0)->Rendering<<endl;

    QStringList test = QgsApplication::deferredSkippedGdalDrivers();
    QString settings =  QgsApplication::showSettings();
    qDebug()<<"this is just settings : "<<settings;


    cout<<"count of test items"<<test.count()<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<test.count();i++){
        cout<<"entered to loop"<<endl;
        cout<<"this is the list of skipped"<<test[i].toStdString()<<endl;
    }

    //mapcanvas->layer(0)->setAutoRefreshEnabled(true);
    //mapcanvas->layer(1)->setAutoRefreshEnabled(true);
    //mapcanvas->setMapUpdateInterval(500);
    //rast3dLayer->setRenderer(renderer3d);


    mapcanvas->enableAntiAliasing(true);
    mapcanvas->refresh();
//mapcanvas->setParallelRenderingEnabled(true);
    //rastLayer->renderer()->set
    mapcanvas->setCachingEnabled(true);
    mapcanvas->show();
    //mapcanvas->setCurrentLayer(rastLayer);
//mapcanvas->redrawAllLayers();
    //rastLayer->triggerRepaint(true);
    //rast3dLayer->triggerRepaint(true);

//mapcanvas->layer(0)->setSubLayerVisibility("rastLayer",false);
//mapcanvas->layer(2)->
//mapcanvas->refresh();



    cout<<"the count of layers is : " << mapcanvas->layerCount()<<endl;


    int retval = app.exec();

    app.exitQgis();


    return retval;
}
```

Everything is ok except the loading of ECW formats in QGIS. I read some sources to how add ECW format to QGIS but all of them are just about the QGIS software not about QGIS C++ API. I can see ECW files in my qgis-dev software but in my program I couldn't do that. When I run my program in Qt see this logs in application output :

```
12:55:15: The program has unexpectedly finished.
12:55:15: The process was ended forcefully.
12:55:15: C:/Users/Test/Desktop/build-testQGISLib-Desktop_Qt_5_12_1_MSVC2015_64bit-Debug/debug/testQGISLib.exe crashed.

12:55:15: Starting C:\Users\Test\Desktop\build-testQGISLib-Desktop_Qt_5_12_1_MSVC2015_64bit-Debug\debug\testQGISLib.exe...
..\..\..\src\core\qgsapplication.cpp(160) : (QgsApplication::QgsApplication) [0ms] loading of qgis translation failed C:/Users/Test/Desktop/build-testQGISLib-Desktop_Qt_5_12_1_MSVC2015_64bit-Debug/debug/./i18n//qgis_
..\..\..\src\core\qgsapplication.cpp(175) : (QgsApplication::QgsApplication) [0ms] loading of qt translation failed C:/Qt/Qt5.12.1/5.12.1/msvc2015_64/translations/qt_
..\..\..\src\core\qgsproviderregistry.cpp(133) : (QgsProviderRegistry::init) [36ms] Checking C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/gdal-dev/bin/gdalplugins for provider plugins
..\..\..\src\core\qgsproviderregistry.cpp(193) : (QgsProviderRegistry::init) [8ms] Checking C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/gdal-dev/bin/gdalplugins/gdal_ECW_JP2ECW.dll: ...invalid (no providerMetadataFactory method)
..\..\..\src\core\qgsproviderregistry.cpp(215) : (QgsProviderRegistry::init) [0ms] Loaded 4 providers (gdal;memory;mesh_memory;ogr) 
..\..\..\src\core\qgsapplication.cpp(1686) : (QgsApplication::applyGdalSkippedDrivers) [0ms] Gdal Skipped driver list set to:
..\..\..\src\core\qgsapplication.cpp(1687) : (QgsApplication::applyGdalSkippedDrivers) [0ms] 
..\..\..\src\core\providers\ogr\qgsogrprovider.cpp(3287) : (createFilters) [6ms] Unknown driver VICAR for file filters.
..\..\..\src\core\providers\ogr\qgsogrprovider.cpp(3287) : (createFilters) [0ms] Unknown driver EEDA for file filters.

rend is 1024
count of test items0
the count of layers is : 2
```

Here is my pro file :

```
   #-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2020-02-13T15:54:14
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT += core xml gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = testQGISLib
TEMPLATE = app

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which has been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

CONFIG += c++11

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
        mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
        mainwindow.ui

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

INCLUDEPATH +=  "C:/OSGeo4W64/include"
DEPENDPATH += "C:/OSGeo4W64/include"
INCLUDEPATH +=  "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-dev/include"
DEPENDPATH += "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-dev/include"
LIBS += -L"C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-dev/lib" -lqgis_core -lqgis_gui

#LIBS += -L"C:/Users/Test/AppData/Local/Hexagon/ERDAS ECW JPEG 2000 SDK 5.5.0/Desktop Read-Only/lib/vc140/x64" -lNCSEcw
#INCLUDEPATH += "C:/Users/Test/AppData/Local/Hexagon/ERDAS ECW JPEG 2000 SDK 5.5.0/Desktop Read-Only/include"


#LIBS += -L"C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/gdal-dev/lib" -lgdal_i
#INCLUDEPATH +=  "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/gdal-dev/include"



INCLUDEPATH += "C:/Qt/Qt5.12.1/5.12.1/msvc2015_64/include"
DEPENDPATH += "C:/Qt/Qt5.12.1/5.12.1/msvc2015_64/include"
#INCLUDEPATH += "C:/Qt/Qt5.12.1/5.12.1/msvc2015_64/bin"
#INCLUDEPATH += "C:/OSGeo4W64/bin"
#INCLUDEPATH += "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-dev"
#INCLUDEPATH += "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-dev/bin"
#DEPENDPATH += "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-dev"
#DEPENDPATH += "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-dev/bin"
LIBS += -L"C:/Qt/Qt5.12.1/5.12.1/msvc2015_64/lib" -lQt5Core -lQt5Gui -lQt5Xml
LIBS += -L"C:/Qt/Qt5.12.1/5.12.1/msvc2015_64/lib" -lQt5Cored -lQt5Guid -lQt5Xmld



DEFINES+=CORE_EXPORT=
DEFINES+=GUI_EXPORT=
```

- QGIS-DEV 3.13
- QT Creator 4.8.1
- OS : windows 10
- Compiler : msvc2015

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

it seems that part of my problem is solved. the problem was that i forgot to specify GDAL_PATH_DRIVER for the program as in QGIS Desktop. i just have a look to *.env files in OSGEO_ROOT (for me is in c drive) and use exactly addresses that is used there and start qtCreator by this environmental variables and bomb... ecw files executed rightly. the addresses for me like this :

```
set OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W64

SET PYTHONHOME=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python37
SET PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONHOME%;%PYTHONHOME%\Scripts
PATH %PYTHONPATH%;%PATH%

SET PROJ_LIB=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\proj-dev\share\proj
PATH %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\proj-dev\bin;%PATH%

SET GDAL_DATA=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\gdal-dev\share\gdal
SET GDAL_DRIVER_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\gdal-dev\bin\gdalplugins
PATH %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\gdal-dev\bin;%PATH%

path %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis-dev\bin;%PATH%
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT:\=/%/apps/qgis-dev
set GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8=YES
rem Set VSI cache to be used as buffer, see #6448
set VSI_CACHE=TRUE
set VSI_CACHE_SIZE=1000000

start "qtcreator" /B C:\Qt\Qt5.12.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\qtcreator.exe %*
```